# Query selector an element with parent id and child class mixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Example:

```
<div id="dataTableColToggler">
<a class="toggle-vis col0" data-column="0" >Col 0</a> - 
<a class="toggle-vis col1" data-column="1" >Col 1</a> - 
<a class="toggle-vis col2" data-column="2" >Col 2</a>
</div>
```

How can i get the element Col 1 with querySelector?

Comment: you can not put tow classes attribute in one tag

Comment: All of those links only have one class, `toggle-vis`. You can not _repeat_ HTML attributes on an element!

Comment: I forgot that that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the `Col 1`, you should use:

```
var col2 = document.querySelector("#dataTableColToggler .col1");
```

But you should **not duplicate** the `class` attribute. Use the classes as given below:

```js
var col2 = document.querySelector("#dataTableColToggler .col1");
console.log(col2.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="dataTableColToggler">
  <a class="toggle-vis col0" data-column="0">Col 0</a> -
  <a class="toggle-vis col1" data-column="1">Col 1</a> -
  <a class="toggle-vis col2" data-column="2">Col 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT** put tow `classes attribute` in one `tag`
**Learn about class `attribute` here:**https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp

```js
var col2 = document.querySelector("#dataTableColToggler .col2");
console.log(col2);
```

```html
<div id="dataTableColToggler">
<a class="toggle-vis col0" data-column="0">Col 0</a> - 
<a class="toggle-vis col1" data-column="1">Col 1</a> - 
<a class="toggle-vis col2" data-column="2">Col 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.innerText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) method to access the value of the col.

You've made a mistake specifying twice the keyword `class=""`

---

Look at the following snippet :

```js
var col2 = document.querySelector("#dataTableColToggler .col2").innerText;

console.log(col2);
```

```html
<div id="dataTableColToggler">
  <a data-column="0" class="toggle-vis col0">Col 0</a> -
  <a data-column="1" class="toggle-vis col1">Col 1</a> -
  <a data-column="2" class="toggle-vis col2">Col 2</a>
</div>
```